# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\ln(e^x+1)}-\sqrt{x}\right)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

The question is to evaluate $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\ln(e^x+1)}-\sqrt{x}\right)^{1/x}$$

This is an indeterminate form of type $0^0$, so I've tried using the identity $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ and somehow apply l'Hospital's, which leads to pretty complex derivatives and I'm getting nowhere. I've also tried multiplying by the conjugate and perhaps factorize, without success.

Comment: As always, limited expansions are the best way. But if, for some reason, one wants to avoid them, then multiplying by the conjugate quantity yields $$\sqrt{\ln(e^x+1)}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{\ln(e^x+1)-x}{\sqrt{\ln(e^x+1)}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\ln(1+e^{-x})}{\sqrt{x+\ln(1+e^{-x})}+\sqrt{x}}$$ Now, the limits of $$(\ln(1+e^{-x})^{1/x}$$ and $$(\sqrt{x+\ln(1+e^{-x})}+\sqrt{x})^{1/x}$$ should be clear. Are they to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
\begin{align}
\bigg(\sqrt{\ln(e^x+1)}-\sqrt{x}\bigg)^{1/x}&=
x^{1/(2x)}\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{\ln(1+e^{-x})}{x}}-1\bigg)^{1/x}\\
&=x^{1/(2x)}\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{e^{-x}+o(e^{-x})}{x}}-1\bigg)^{1/x}\\
&= x^{1/(2x)}\bigg(1+\frac{e^{-x}}{2 x}+o(e^{-x}/x)-1\bigg)^{1/x}\\
&= \frac{x^{1/(2x)}}{(2x)^{1/x}}\cdot e^{-1}\bigg(1+o(1)\bigg)^{1/x}
\end{align}
where we used the following expansions at $t=0$: $\ln(1+t)=t+o(t)$,  $\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}+o(t)$.
So, what is the limit as $x\to +\infty$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\log\left(e^x+1\right)}-\sqrt{x}
&=\sqrt{x+\log\left(1+e^{-x}\right)}-\sqrt{x}\\
&=\frac{\log\left(1+e^{-x}\right)}{\sqrt{x+\log\left(1+e^{-x}\right)}+\sqrt{x}}
\end{align}
$$